# GET rid of a page from browser history

Tags: php, state, browser-history

I have a page for example, say first.html. it has a form with action set to, say xyz.php.
This php file ,after processing , sends a header () with location . Now browser fetches the page.
Now when I click back button ,first.html shows.
Is there a way to get rid of that first.html page and show other page from history?

Answer (score 0):

When there's a redirect if you want to replace the page that triggered the redirect you can use `window.location.replace(newUrl)`.

[Here's the documentation for replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)